# Uso de estados - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es tras mapear un arreglo de objetos y plasmar sus datos en una tabla, al momento de hacer clic en el primer campo de cada fila realizar un envío de toda la información que existe en la fila a otro componente. Estoy haciendo uso de estados, pero no estaría logrando hacer que el objeto capturado sea envíado. Dicho de otra manera, el componente **TableCell** tiene que pasarle al **Form** el objeto indicado. Con el código me van a entender mejor.

```
  const [capturedValue, value]: any = React.useState({});

  const passData = (d: any) => {
    value(d); // Objeto capturado { id, name, etc }
  };

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" className="HomeMenu">
      <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{ maxWidth: '87%', marginLeft: '2em' }}>
        <Table aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.id}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.siteCode}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.url}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.icon}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.type}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.description}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.slug}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.parent}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.order}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.active}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.userchange}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.datechange}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.parent_id}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.urlpath}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.apiUrl}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((row: any) => (
                <TableRow key={row.id}>
                  <TableCell
                    sx={{ color: 'green', fontWeight: 'bold', cursor: 'pointer' }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleClickOpen();
                      passData(row);  // capturo el objeto { id, name, etc }
                    }}
                  >
                    {row.name || noInfo}

                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.id || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.siteCode || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.url || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.icon || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.type || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.description || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.slug || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.parent || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.order || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.active || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.userchange || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.datechange || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.parent_id || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.urlpath || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.apiUrl || noInfo}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
        <TableFooter>
          <TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[7, 10]}
            component="div"
            count={data.length}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onPageChange={handleChangePage}
            onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
          />
        </TableFooter>
      </TableContainer>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle>Use Google location service?</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
            <Form data={capturedValue} /> // Objeto capturado y enviado { id, name, etc }
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="error">{label.close}</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Stack>
  );
```

Componente Form:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Box,
  TextField,
} from '@mui/material';

export interface IFormProps {
  data: any;
}

function Form(props: any) {
  const { data } = props;

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <div>
        <TextField
          disabled
          id="outlined-required"
          label="Required"
          defaultValue={data.siteCode}
        />
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: ¿De qué manera estás recibiendo el dato enviado en el componente `<Form>`? ¿Lo haces con las `props`? O sea, haciendo un `props.data` para acceder.

Comment: actualizo el código para que lo puedas ver. Pero si hago un console.log por ejemplo de capturedValue no sale nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar. La cuestión es que estaba haciendo mal al crear una nueva función, en este caso llamada passData() porque value ya está cumpliendo el rol de función encargada de capturar el valor que deseo. Entonces, lo que hice fue eliminar la primer función, asignarle un nombre más descriptivo a mi variable y con eso estaría. Basta con pasarle al componente Form lo que se le asigna automáticamente a capturedValue.

```
const [capturedValue, setValue] = React.useState({});

 return (
    <Stack direction="row" className="HomeMenu">
      <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{ maxWidth: '87%', marginLeft: '2em' }}>
        <Table aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.name}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.id}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.siteCode}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.url}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.icon}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.type}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.description}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.slug}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.parent}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.order}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.active}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.userchange}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.datechange}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.parent_id}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.urlpath}</TableCell>
              <TableCell sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{label.apiUrl}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((row: any) => (
                <TableRow key={row.id}>
                  <TableCell
                    sx={{ color: 'green', fontWeight: 'bold', cursor: 'pointer' }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleClickOpen();
                      setValue(row);
                    }}
                  >
                    {row.name || noInfo}

                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.id || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.siteCode || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.url || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.icon || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.type || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.description || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.slug || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.parent || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.order || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.active || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.userchange || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.datechange || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.parent_id || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.urlpath || noInfo}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.apiUrl || noInfo}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
        <TableFooter>
          <TablePagination
            rowsPerPageOptions={[7, 10]}
            component="span"
            count={data.length}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onPageChange={handleChangePage}
            onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
          />
        </TableFooter>
      </TableContainer>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle>Use Google location service?</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
            <Form data={capturedValue} />
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="error">{label.close}</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </Stack>
  );
```